# How to arrange the rows in a specific order

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 7

```
ID Name

001 Raja
002 Vijay
003 Suresh
004 Mahes
005 Salma
```

I want to arrange by id (003, 001, 004, 002, 005)

Expected output

```
ID Name

003 Suresh
001 Raja
004 Mahes
002 Vijay
005 Salma
```

Note: Maximum row is 5 only, it will not exceed more than 5.

I need to add 5 group or any other method is there for arranging the rows.

Need Crystal report formula or suggestion help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In later versions of crystal you can set a custom sort order but if this feature isn't available in CR7 you should be able to create a formula:

```
if {table.id} = '003' then
 1
else if {table.id} = '001' then
 2
else if {table.id} = '004' then
 3
else if {table.id} = '002' then
 4
else if {table.id} = '005' then
 5
else
 999;
```

Then sort on that formula.